# Shouldn't the "even parity" function map 1101 to 0?

Tags: logic

From the book *Computer organization and design* by Patterson&Hennessy:

> **Parity** is a function in which the output depends on the number of 1s in in the input. For an *even* parity function, the output is 1 if the input has an even number of ones. Suppose a ROM is used to implement an even parity function with a 4-bit input. Then the contents of the ROM is
>   $$\text{Address} \ 0 : \ 0 \\ \text{Address} \ 1: \ 1 \\ \text{Address} \ 2 : \ 0 \\ \text{Address} \ 3 : \ 1 \\ \vdots \\ \text{Address} \ 13 : \ 1 \\ \text{Address} \ 14 : \ 0 \\ \text{Address} \ 15 : \ 1$$

As per my understanding, ROM which implements the *even* parity function should store 0 at both the Address 1 and the Address 2, 1 at the Address 3, ... 0 at both the Address 13 and 14, then 1 at the Address 15, for the Address $k$ to represent the map-value of $(k)_{\text{base}2}$.

According to this the concept defined above is not clear enough, Can someone clarify the doubt?

Comment: You seem to be correct.

Comment: why output for address zero (0000) is 0 ? since it has zero number of 1s, which is even, does't make its output to be 1 ?

Comment: @avi, I'm not in trouble with Address 0 since depending on convention 0 might be even or odd ... My problem is not there.

Comment: But that isn't the even parity function, it's the odd parity function.

Comment: @giuscri What do you mean, "depending on convention 0 might be even or odd"? The parity of zero isn't a matter of convention: it's a simple arithmetic fact that zero is even, since it leaves no remainder when divided by two!

Comment: To clarify the question (which, for some reason, I can't edit), the context is actually an exercise on page B-20 of the 5th edition of Patterson and Hennessy. The question presents four different ROMs and asks which one of them implements the even parity function (defined as in the quote). Unfortunately, the four functions implemented are a) MSB of the input; b) negation of MSB; c) negation of LSB of the input; d) LSB. None of the four options implements the even parity function.

Comment: @DavidRicherby , oops, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, implementing something as a ROM just means a look-up table. If you want to know the parity of $x$, you put the binary coding of $x$ on the ROM's address wires and the value you read out is the value stored at that memory location within the ROM, which will be either 0 or 1.

And, yes, the contents of the ROM that you've quoted are wrong: they seem to be implementing parity in the sense that the output is 1 if, and only if, the input is an odd number, instead of implementing the even parity function.

Comment: Its actually an exercise question, here is the link : http://bit.ly/17Z0aZQ

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't *exactly* an answer to the question, I will say that the Appendix of this edition is full of errors, including some really silly stuff on page B-12 claiming that an input is an output, and failing to include "+" between the sum of products. While I was able to track down the official errata list (https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124077263/downloads/COD5e_errata_09-2014.pdf), it doesn't look like anything in Appendix B has been listed.